# C# webcam with DShow.Net/ DirectX.Capture: show devices names

Tags: c#, directx, webcam, directshow

Good day. I controll my usb webcam with DShow.Net/ DirectX.Capture. It found and initialize all connected devices but it show names of devices to own button with number (1.2.3 ... ) . I want to show full name of devices. My code example:

```
if (filters.VideoInputDevices != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < filters.VideoInputDevices.Count; i++)
                {
                    var device = filters.VideoInputDevices[i];

                    var btn = new Button();

                    btn.Text = i.ToString();
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    btn.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
                    btn.Width = 50;

                    btn.Click += (obj, evt) =>
                    {
                        var thisButton = (Button)obj;

                        if (int.Parse(thisButton.Text) != deviceName)
                        {
                            if (capture != null)
                            {
                                capture.Dispose();
                                capture.Stop();
                                capture.PreviewWindow = null;
                            }

                            deviceName = int.Parse(thisButton.Text);
                            preview(deviceName);
                        }
                    };

                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the library you're talking about. If you can point me out to a documentation I can probably be more help to you. But your problem lies in `btn.Text = i.ToString();`. You need to write it instead to something like `btn.Text = device.Name;` or something. Again, documentation will help you determine what you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
btn.Text = i.ToString();
```

to

```
btn.Text = device.Name;
```

Then

```
if (int.Parse(thisButton.Text) != deviceName)
```

to

```
if (thisButton.Text != deviceName)
```

Note that a rule of thumb asking question on StackOverflow is:

- research effort
- minimal understanding of the problem solved

Comment: You got an error because of `int.Parse(thisButton.Text)` you're trying to parse a text to an `int`.

Comment: i cannot use if (thisButton.Text != deviceName) because i got error Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: And change `deviceName = int.Parse(thisButton.Text);` into `deviceName = thisButton.Text;` and devicename to string. @Fakt7 if you get a new error, ask a separate question where you also explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: It surely is possible to fix it, but as mentioned by Roman R., you need to research understand more your code. We will fix this part for you, but another part of your program will break. I cannot see where you are setting `deviceName`, and I don't even know what is the type of deviceName, is it an int, string, double?
Be more concise with your question.

Roman R., +1 btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Do something Like this .

```
 if (filters.VideoInputDevices != null)
 {
 for (var i = 0; i < filters.VideoInputDevices.Count; i++)
 {
 var device = filters.VideoInputDevices[i];
```

here Device has a collection so you have to Store in an Array and then split

```
string Decive[] = device.split('');//Split it based on some parameter 
// Change Here 
var btn = new Button();
btn.text = Device[1].text ;'

/// Rest of the Code will be same i think so
```